# How to auto populate Date picker field values in two fields

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have two date picker fields in the list, one is hidden from the form. And my client want the hidden one to be auto populated with the same value when the other one has value.
JS would be recommended.

This is what I tried...

```
function autoPopulate() {
  var first = document.getElementById('First Date'),
    second = document.getElementById('Second Date');
  first.onkeyup = function() {
    second.value = first.value;
  };
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and, if applicable, using your own code you are having issues with, [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh Sorry, This is what I tried...                                                             function autoPopulate(){
var first = document.getElementById('First Date'),
second = document.getElementById('Second Date');
first.onkeyup = function () { 
second.value = first.value;
 };
}

Answer (score 0):

here is a small example how I inserted the value in the hidden field and how I used it in some other variable

```js
var mydate = document.getElementById("demo").value = Date();
var hidden = document.getElementById('myField').value = mydate;
document.getElementById('printdate').innerHTML = hidden
```

```html
<input type="text" style="width:500px" id="demo">
<input type="hidden" id="myField">
<p id="printdate"> is the hidden value that showing hidden date that we stored in hidden variable</p>
```